Flutter Not able to list files in android
    Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
    List<FileSystemEntity> files = dir.listSync(followLinks: false);
    print(files);

I want to list files from the Download folder on android, but this only gives directories.

This is solved with permission:

and
PermissionStatus status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
